# Simple neural-network simulation in C++ (Round 2)

Tags: c++, performance, numerical-methods, neural-network, eigen

## Intro

Yesterday I posted [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/107621/84610).  Since then, I've updated my code to incorporate [these](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/107726/84610) suggestions.  I've also removed the dependence on C++11.  Finally, I've made the following changes that get me closer to my overall goal:

- Rather than iterate over different values for `dt` within my script, I have `dt` specified on the command line.  Specifically, an integer is specified on the command line that corresponds to (1 +) an index in `dt_array`.  This allows me to process different values of `dt` in parallel using the Sun Grid Engine.
- Rather than use a single value for `I_syn_bar`, I now iterate over 100 values of `I_syn_bar`.

If you read through the current state of my script below, you'll see that I'm writing to disk 100 text files per `dt`.  When I set `n_x` to 2 instead of 100, the script is very fast: 6 s on my machine.  But when I set `n_x` to 100, and submit the script as a job to the SGE, it takes ~1 hour to complete (more than 6 s * 50).  Hence, there seems to be some penalty being imposed on me for the heavy file I/O I'm using (in addition to the general SGE overhead).

**My goal now is to change the code so that I'm writing the data for all 100 values of `I_syn_bar`, but in fewer files.**  I have a 2D matrix for each value of `I_syn_bar`.  In order to write data for multiple values of `I_syn_bar` to the same text file, I need a 3D object of some kind (and a strategy for writing this object to file).  Another constraint I have is that I need these files to be able to be read into Python.

## Code

```
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
using Eigen::ArrayXd;

bool save_mat(const MatrixXd& pdata, const std::stringstream& file_path)
{
  std::ofstream os(file_path.str().c_str());
  if (!os.is_open())
    {
      std::cout << "Failure!" << std::endl;
      return false;
    }
  os.precision(11);
  const int n_rows = pdata.rows();
  const int n_cols = pdata.cols();
  for (int i = 0; i < n_rows; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < n_cols; j++)
        {
          os << pdata(i, j);
          if (j + 1 == n_cols)
            {
              os << std::endl;
            }
          else
            {
              os << ",";
            }
        }
    }
  os.close();
  return true;
}

std::string get_save_file()
{
  std::string dan_dir;
  struct stat statbuf;
  if (stat("/home/daniel", &statbuf) == 0 && S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode))
    {
      dan_dir = "/home/daniel/Science";
    }
  else if (stat("/home/dan", &statbuf) == 0 && S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode))
    {
      dan_dir = "/home/dan/Science";
    }
  else if (stat("/home/despo", &statbuf) == 0 && S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode))
    {
      dan_dir = "/home/despo/dbliss";
    }
  std::string save_file = "/dopa_net/results/hansel/test/test_hansel";
  save_file = dan_dir + save_file;
  return save_file;
}

double f(const double t, const double tau_1, const double tau_2)
{
  return tau_2 / (tau_1 - tau_2) * (exp(-t / tau_1) - exp(-t / tau_2));
}

ArrayXd set_initial_V(const double tau, const double g_L, const double I_0,
                      const double theta, const double V_L, const int N,
                      const double c)
{
  const double T = -tau * log(1 - g_L / I_0 * (theta - V_L));
  ArrayXd V(N);
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      V(i) = V_L + I_0 / g_L * (1 - exp(-c * (i - 1) / N * T / tau));
    }
  return V;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  // Declare variables set inside loops below.
  double t;
  double I_syn_bar;
  int i;
  std::stringstream complete_save_file;

  // Declare and initialize constant parameters.
  const int n_x = 100;
  const double x_min = 0;   // uA / cm^2.
  const double x_max = 1;   // uA / cm^2.
  const double x_step = (x_max - x_min) / (n_x - 1);  // uA / cm^2.
  const double tau_1 = 3.0;  // ms.
  const double tau_2 = 1.0;  // ms.
  const int N = 128;
  const double dt_array[3] = {0.25, 0.1, 0.01};  // ms.
  const char* task_id = argv[argc - 1];
  const int task_id_int = task_id[0] - '0';
  const double dt = dt_array[task_id_int - 1];
  const double tau = 10;  // ms.
  const double g_L = 0.1;  // mS / cm^2.
  const double I_0 = 2.3;  // uA / cm^2.
  const double theta = -40;  // mV.
  const double V_L = -60;  // mV.
  const double c = 0.5;
  const double C = 1;  // uF / cm^2.
  const int sim_t = 10000;  // ms.
  const int n_t = sim_t / dt;
  const std::string save_file = get_save_file();

  // Save V for each I_syn_bar, for the dt specified on the command line.
  for (double I_syn_bar = x_min; I_syn_bar < x_max; I_syn_bar += x_step)
    {
      MatrixXd V(N, n_t);
      V.col(0) = set_initial_V(tau, g_L, I_0, theta, V_L, N, c);
      double I_syn = 0;  // uA / cm^2.
      ArrayXd t_spike_array = ArrayXd::Zero(N);
      i = 1;
      for (double t = dt; t < sim_t; t += dt)
        {
          ArrayXd prev_V = V.col(i - 1).array();
          ArrayXd current_V = prev_V + dt * (-g_L * (prev_V - V_L) + I_syn +
                                             I_0) / C;
          V.col(i) = current_V;
          I_syn = 0;
          for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
              if (current_V(j) > theta)
                {
                  t_spike_array(j) = t;
                  V(j, i) = V_L;
                }
              I_syn += I_syn_bar / N * f(t - t_spike_array(j), tau_1, tau_2);
            }
          i++;
        }
      complete_save_file << save_file << dt << "_" << I_syn_bar << ".txt";
      save_mat(V, complete_save_file);
      complete_save_file.str("");
      complete_save_file.clear();
    }
  return 0;

}
```

## Timing Information

```
---------------------------------------------
| n_x | command-line arg | SGE? | Time      |
---------------------------------------------
| 2   |         1        | no   | 6 s       |
---------------------------------------------
| 2   |         1        | yes  | 30 s      |
---------------------------------------------
| 100 |         1        | no   | 10 m 16 s |
---------------------------------------------
| 100 |         1        | yes  | 53 m 5 s  |
---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Well, in the save-code you have some superfluous flushes. I suggest removing them, but that's all I see just now. BTW, why make it C++03 compatible? (Just because you can is fine, though I'm curious.)

Comment: The stream-manipulator `std::endl` doesn't only cause a single `'\n'` to be inserted, but causes an explicit flush afterwards. If the latter isn't needed, that's just tthrowing away your performance.

Comment: The code you posted run an infinite loop due to the computing of `x_step`. You are using an integer division resulting in `x_step=0` with the parameters you have posted. Pleae make sure that the code you posted is an actual working example.

Comment: note that `n_x` must be an integer greater than or equal to 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you skim the relevant part of the paper which this analysis is attempting to replicate (cf. the link in the Round 1 question), you'll see that my code saves an intermediate result on the way to the final result that is plotted in Figure 1.  Figure 1 plots `sigma_N`, whereas I'm saving `V` here.

For each `I_syn_bar`, `V` is a matrix of size number of neurons by number of time points.  This is a lot of data to save.  `sigma_N` takes up much less space: a single double for each `I_syn_bar`.

I made two fairly small changes to my code:

- I followed the advice in the comments and replaced all appearances of `endl` with `"\n"`.
- I carried out the analysis through the computation of `sigma_N` and saved `sigma_N` instead of `V`.

`sigma_N`, in my new code, is defined as follows (within, but at the very end of, the loop over `I_syn_bar`):

```
  // Compute A_N.
  A_N = V.colwise().mean();

  // Compute delta_N.
  delta_N = A_N.square().mean() - pow(A_N.mean(), 2);

  // Compute delta.
  V_squared = V.unaryExpr(std::ptr_fun(square));
  V_squared_time_mean = V_squared.rowwise().mean();
  V_time_mean = V.rowwise().mean();
  V_time_mean_squared = V_time_mean.square();
  delta = (V_squared_time_mean - V_time_mean_squared).mean();

  // Compute sigma_N.
  sigma_N_array[j] = delta_N / delta;
```

## The Crux of this Answer

**Let me restate this: In the code in the Round 2 question above, I'm saving 100 matrices of size `N` X `n_t` to disk, where `N` is 128 and `n_t` is 40000 (if `dt` is 0.25).  As I mention in the question, all this file-writing is causing the code to be undesirably slow.**

**MY SOLUTION HERE is to carry the analysis a step farther.  Rather than save all these matrices, I save the variable they will eventually be used to compute: `sigma_N`.  Whereas `V` (what was originally saved) is 100 X 128 X 40000, `sigma_N` is 100 X 1.**

**Although the extra analysis step adds a tiny amount of time, this is far outweighed by the time saved by not having to write all those large matrices.**

**If you don't understand what `sigma_N` is, please, as I said, consult the earlier question and the paper linked there.  If you are unwilling to do this, or otherwise don't understand what I'm saying, *please ask me to clarify a particular point*.  I am happy to do that.**

## Timing Information

```
----------------------------------------------
| n_x | command-line arg  | SGE? | Time      |
----------------------------------------------
| 2   |         1         | no   | 0.4 s     |
----------------------------------------------
| 2   |         1         | yes  | 1.2 s     |
----------------------------------------------
| 100 |         1         | no   | 41.4 s    |
----------------------------------------------
| 100 |         1         | yes  | 49.1 s    |
----------------------------------------------
| 100 | 1-3 (in parallel) | yes  | 18 m 28 s |
----------------------------------------------
```

Note, with regard to the last line of the table above, that the code is dramatically slower with `3` as the command-line argument (`dt = 0.01`) than with `2` or `1`.

## Caveat

Everything about the Round 1 question, the Round 1 answer, the Round 2 question, and this answer is great and wonderful when it comes to considering factors that influence the speed of a C++ script.

However, it turns out that this script overlooks a number of considerations that are needed in order to replicate Figure 1.  I've made tweaks to the script in a few places to handle this.  Since these considerations are outside the scope of both this question and the Round 1 question, I'm not going to describe them here.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30376/discussion-on-answer-by-dbliss-simple-neural-network-simulation-in-c-round-2).