# Simple neural-network simulation in C++ (Round 4)

Tags: c++, numerical-methods, neural-network

You may want to take a look at Rounds [1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/107621/84610), [2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/107805/84610), and [3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/107961/84610), though that isn't necessary for understanding what's below.

The major change since Round 3 is that my code is *much* cleaner and I'm including profiling information here.

Here's my script:

```
#include "hansel.h"
#include <deque>


int main()
{

  // Parameters.
  const double tau = 10;
  const double g_l = 0.1;
  const double I_0 = 2.3;
  const double theta = -40;
  const double V_l = -60;
  const double c = 0.5;
  const double N = 128;
  const double I_syn_bar = 0;
  const double tau_1 = 3;
  const double tau_2 = 1;
  const double C = 1;
  const double Delta_t = 0.25;

  // Simulation.
  std::deque<double> spike_times;
  double V = set_initial_V(tau, g_l, I_0, theta, V_l, c, N);
  for (double t = 0; t < 10000; t += Delta_t)
    {
      double I_syn = get_I_syn(I_syn_bar, N, tau_1, tau_2, t, spike_times);
      double dV_dt = get_dV_dt(g_l, V, V_l, I_syn, I_0, C);
      V += Delta_t * dV_dt;
      if (V > theta)
        {
          V = V_l;
          spike_times.push_back(t + Delta_t);
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the header file it includes:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <deque>


const double get_T(const double tau, const double g_l, const double I_0,
                   const double theta, const double V_l)
{
  return -tau * log(1 - g_l / I_0 * (theta - V_l));
}


double set_initial_V(const double tau, const double g_l, const double I_0,
                     const double theta, const double V_l, const double c,
                     const double N)
{
  const double T = get_T(tau, g_l, I_0, theta, V_l);
  const double i = 1;
  return V_l + I_0 / g_l * (1 - exp(-c * (i - 1) / N * T / tau));
}


double get_dV_dt(const double g_l, const double V, const double V_l,
                 const double I_syn, const double I_0, const double C)
{
  return (-g_l * (V - V_l) + I_syn + I_0) / C;
}


double get_f(const double tau_1, const double tau_2, const double t)
{
  return 1 / (tau_1 - tau_2) * (exp(-t / tau_1) - exp(-t / tau_2));
}


double get_I_syn(const double I_syn_bar, const double N, const double tau_1,
                 const double tau_2, const double t,
                 const std::deque<double> & spike_times)
{
  double sum_f = 0;
  const int n_spikes = spike_times.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < n_spikes; i += 1)
    {
      sum_f += get_f(tau_1, tau_2, t - spike_times[i]);
    }
  return I_syn_bar / N * sum_f;
}
```

Profiling the script, I see that ~100% of the time is spent in calls to `get_I_syn`.  Within that, time is split between calls to `get_f` (50.1%) and use of the `deque` `[]` operator (45.4%).

I'm hoping to speed up this script by a factor of ~10.

## **My questions are**

1) Is there a way to refactor this line to increase speed:

```
return 1 / (tau_1 - tau_2) * (exp(-t / tau_1) - exp(-t / tau_2));
```

2) Is there a way to vectorize (or otherwise speed up) this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n_spikes; i += 1)
  {
     sum_f += get_f(tau_1, tau_2, t - spike_times[i]);
  }
```

3) Is it likely to be faster to use an `array` or a `vector` instead of the `deque` object?

Comment: switching to a `vector` got me to a total computing time of `~5s` as compared to the original `~7s`.  (this is still far too slow.)  after this change, i'm spending `~88.8%` of the time in `get_f`.  i'm wondering whether i need a larger algorithmic change to `get_I_syn`.  maybe i should pre-compute values for `get_f` for the full range of values for `t-spike_times[i]` i'm expecting to get?

Comment: for reference, the paper i'm replicating, from 1998 (see the Round 1 question for a link to the paper), reports that it takes `~5s` to run a `10-s` simulation of `138` neurons.  it takes me this long to simulate just `1` neuron for `10 s`.

Comment: i should also mention that `75.3%` of the time is spent in `exp` -- so it's really the use of this `math` function over and over again that's slowing me down.

Comment: is this the full working example that takes `7s`? What compiler with what options are you using on what kind of a machine? On my `i7-4790K` with `gcc5.2 -O3` it runsin `0.25s`.

Comment: @Zulan yep, this is the full working example.  i get `8 s` using the `-O3` compiler option.  i'm not sure exactly what to tell you about my machine.  this is the processor info: `Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T5250 @ 1.50GHz × 2`.  it's an old machine, but not 1998 old.

Comment: [potentially relevant question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11658275/2623899).

Comment: @Zulan i just ran it on a larger computing cluster and got a run time within a second.  OK.  maybe this is just not the sort of script i can run on my laptop.  (still, if there are not-incredibly-complicated ways to refactor this to make it faster, i'd want to do that.)  even with `0.25 s` for one neuron, i'm expecting that to scale as `N ^ 2` as i ramp up to the full population (`N = 138` neurons).

Comment: i keep saying `138` neurons for the full population -- but i mean `128`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `get_I_syn()` currently always returns 0

I'm not sure if you are aware of this, but because `I_syn_bar` is a constant 0, this makes `get_I_syn()` always return 0.  This means you can just get rid of all calls to `get_I_syn()`, which is where 100% of your time is being spent.

However, assuming that there is some mixup here and `I_syn_bar` is supposed to be non-zero, I will explain how you can speed your program up by a factor of 50+.

## Caching return values of `get_f()`

If you look at the `get_f()` function, everything is a constant except for `t`, which is passed in as `t - spike_times[i]` from `get_I_syn()`.  If you look closely at what `t` and `spike_times[i]` are, they are all multiples of `Delta_t`.  In fact, `t - spike_times[i]` can only take on one of 10000 values, which are the first 10000 multiples of `Delta_t`.

Knowing this, you can precompute the 10000 possible values of `get_f()`.  Then inside `get_I_syn()`, you can look up the precomputed values instead of doing the expensive computation.

I modified your program to do this and the program sped up by more than 50x.

## Modified program

Here is the modified program.  I copied the header contents directly into the c++ file for my own convenience.  As you can see, I increased the number of iterations from 10000 to 300000 because otherwise the program ran too fast.

```
#include <deque>
#include <math.h>

const double get_T(const double tau, const double g_l, const double I_0,
                   const double theta, const double V_l)
{
  return -tau * log(1 - g_l / I_0 * (theta - V_l));
}


double set_initial_V(const double tau, const double g_l, const double I_0,
                     const double theta, const double V_l, const double c,
                     const double N)
{
  const double T = get_T(tau, g_l, I_0, theta, V_l);
  const double i = 1;
  return V_l + I_0 / g_l * (1 - exp(-c * (i - 1) / N * T / tau));
}


double get_dV_dt(const double g_l, const double V, const double V_l,
                 const double I_syn, const double I_0, const double C)
{
  return (-g_l * (V - V_l) + I_syn + I_0) / C;
}


double get_f(const double tau_1, const double tau_2, const double t)
{
  return 1 / (tau_1 - tau_2) * (exp(-t / tau_1) - exp(-t / tau_2));
}


double get_I_syn(const double I_syn_bar, const double N, const double *f_cache,
                 const int t_index, const int *spike_times, int n_spikes)
{
    double sum_f = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_spikes; i++)
        sum_f += f_cache[t_index - spike_times[i]];
    return I_syn_bar / N * sum_f;
}

#define ITERATIONS        300000

// Declare in global scope to not overflow the stack.
static double f_cache[ITERATIONS];
static int spike_times[ITERATIONS];

int main()
{
    // Parameters.
    const double tau = 10;
    const double g_l = 0.1;
    const double I_0 = 2.3;
    const double theta = -40;
    const double V_l = -60;
    const double c = 0.5;
    const double N = 128;
    const double I_syn_bar = 2;
    const double tau_1 = 3;
    const double tau_2 = 1;
    const double C = 1;
    const double Delta_t = 0.25;
    int    i = 0;
    double t = 0;

    // Simulation.
    int numSpikes = 0;
    double V = set_initial_V(tau, g_l, I_0, theta, V_l, c, N);

    // Precompute all the possible values returned by get_f().
    for (i = 0, t = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++, t += Delta_t)
        f_cache[i] = get_f(tau_1, tau_2, t);

    for (i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++)
    {
        double I_syn = get_I_syn(I_syn_bar, N, f_cache, i, spike_times,
                numSpikes);
        double dV_dt = get_dV_dt(g_l, V, V_l, I_syn, I_0, C);
        V += Delta_t * dV_dt;
        if (V > theta)
        {
            V = V_l;
            spike_times[numSpikes++] = i + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks very much.  your modification of `get_f` is exactly the sort of thing i wanted to do but wasn't sure how to achieve.  regarding `get_I_syn`, yes, i was aware that it always returns 0.  the script i posted, though complete in a sense, is really a toy version of the full script i'm going for, which will compute `get_I_syn` for a wide range of values of `I_syn_bar`.  (your assumptions about `get_f`, though, hold for the full script, so this answer is very, very helpful.)

Comment: the code in my question uses the Euler method for numerical integration.  i've supplemented this code with an "exact" method, where, rather than go forward in time in steps of `Delta_t`, i analytically solve for the next spike time in the network, and move straight to that time.  this means that the spike times are no longer multiples of `Delta_t`.  hence, it would seem a cache of `f` values no longer helps me.  what would your advice be for this situation?  using `exp` is still very slow.  i'm currently testing "fast" replacements for `exp`.  but maybe the fastest thing would be to vectorize?

Comment: there are also probably compiler options that would speed things up that i haven't considered.  my google searches have revealed that my problem isn't unique, but i'm not seeing a canonical solution anywhere.  it'd be nice to have one.  i'd rather not, but maybe i should post a Round 5 . . .